# Software similar to acrobat reader

Tags: adobe-reader

Is there a software on ubuntu in which we have options like highlighting, underlining, marking text of a pdf document, like in adobe acrobat?

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremly weak point in Ubuntu and Linux in general!

PDFedit is buggy and isn't suited for endusers. It is pdf-engenieering and maybe developement was stopped long time ago.

Xournal is more like drawing.

Scribus imports pdf, as other programs do, like Inkscape, Gimp etc. But this is not the same, as quickly marking some phrase.

Well, I never got Okular working. It refuses to install. Maybe you might get it and it offers what you need, but it will install lots of KDE-services on your Desktop.

I used Foxit with Wine, which was during long time the only solution for making a decent Index in pdf-files. But last time I had an error after a version upgrade. If you really have to do hardcore-pdf-reading then Virtualbox with Acrobat or Foxit Reader might be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try PDFedit.  PDFedit is a free editor for PDF documents. Complete editing of PDF documents is possible with PDFedit. You can change raw pdf objects (for advanced users) or use many GUI functions.

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install pdfedit
```

Or

Scribus.   - Scribus is an open Source Desktop Page Layout / desktop publishing (DTP) application software. Just open file using open option and you can edit PDF file. To  install scribus:

```
sudo apt-get install scribus
```

Or just click [**Scribus** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/scribus/)

<sup>Source:Sourceforge & Scibus</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try Xournal. It has all of features you mentioned.

http://xournal.sourceforge.net/

or

```
sudo apt-get install xournal
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try Okular http://okular.kde.org/

It's a PDF Viewer for KDE and it has cool Text Selection and Review Tools.

You can install it from the main repository :

```
apt-get install okular
```

hope this help... have a nive day